# NHibernate Multi tenant database Second level caching (App fabric) not working properly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, appfabric, second-level-cache

In our wcf service, we are using  Multi tenant database we will switch the database based on user and we are using nhibernate with appfabric for second level caching when second caching is enabled it is returning the cached data for different tenant database when the second level caching is turned off it is working porperly, is there any way to get it work with multi tenant database  with appfabric cache. we are using nhibernate 3.0.0.4000
note: we dont need syscache as it is the memory caching

below is the customprovider to change the tenant based connection string and changed the provider in configuration

```
public class ContextAwareConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets Database Connection String
    /// </summary>
    protected override string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            //If the TenantConnection string is null,set the master Azure SQL db which is used for the initial Tenant identification
            string tenantConnectionString = Convert.ToString(ExtendedConstants.TENANTCONNECTIONSTRING);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantConnectionString))
            {
                return base.ConnectionString;
            }

            return tenantConnectionString;

        }
    }
}
```

`<property name="connection.provider">MyNamespace.ContextAwareConnectionProvider,Myassembly</property>`

Comment: One option I can think of is having Entity Id's unique across databases!